# Async method Firebase

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make my method wait for the execution of the `GetValueAsync` method.

```
public async Task DownloadTopScoreAsync()
{
    await reference.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log("error");
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            // Do something with snapshot...
            Debug.Log("hit");
        }
    });
    return;
}
```

I tried everything, I even copied the ready-made code. But it still gives errors.

> CS0433 The type 'Task' exists in both 'Unity.Tasks, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

> CS0126 An object of a type convertible to 'Task' is required

> CS1061 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The Task class resides inside the [System.Threading.Tasks namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-6.0).

Comment: I am using the given namespace

Comment: What is the type for the "reference" object?

Comment: You have to specify which Task class you are using in your code because it's ambiguos: `Systems.Threading.Task` or `Unity.Tasks`

Answer (score 0):

`using System.Threading.Tasks;` -> `using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;` should do a trick for you.

Comment: Error CS0126 disappeared, but the rest remained. And now error CS0433 appears because of the solution you suggested